# Using the quickCheckAll function in tasty-quickcheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

*Short version*: It is possible to use the `quickCheckAll` function in tasty-quickcheck?

*Long version*:

The `quickCheckAll` function tests **all** properties beginning with `prop_` in the current module as shows the following example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import Test.QuickCheck ( quickCheckAll )

prop_1 :: Int -> Bool
prop_1 x = x + x == 2 * x

prop_2 :: Int -> Int -> Bool
prop_2 x y = x + y == y + x

-- Template Haskell hack to make the following $quickCheckAll work
-- under GHC >= 7.8.
return []

-- All properties as collected by 'quickCheckAll'.
runTests :: IO Bool
runTests = $quickCheckAll

main :: IO ()
main = runTests >> return ()
```

On the other hand, I can use QuickCheck in the Tasty test framework via the tasty-quickcheck package as shows the following example:

```
module Main where

import Test.Tasty ( defaultMain, testGroup, TestTree )

import qualified Test.Tasty.QuickCheck as QC

prop_1 :: Int -> Bool
prop_1 x = x + x == 2 * x

prop_2 :: Int -> Int -> Bool
prop_2 x y = x + y == y + x

tests :: TestTree
tests = testGroup "Tested by QuickCheck"
  [ QC.testProperty "prop_1" prop_1
  , QC.testProperty "prop_2" prop_2
  ]

main :: IO ()
main = defaultMain tests
```

It is possible to use the `quickCheckAll` function on the above example for avoiding **explicitly** listing all the properties when using QuickCheck and Tasty?

Versions: The above examples were tested using GHC 8.2.2, QuickCheck 2.10.1 and tasty-quickcheck 0.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't seem possible with `quickCheckAll` but the underlying logic could be reused by testing frameworks. [Here's a new PR to get all properties in a list.](https://github.com/nick8325/quickcheck/pull/192)